# TSQL - join two tables with TotalCounter and Pagination

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to join 2 tables (one to many relation) that include all the columns from first table and only the number of rows from the second one.

Use case: one Service has many Reviews.

The query looks like:

```
DECLARE @page int = 0;
DECLARE @pageSize int = 10;

SELECT 
    s.Id, COUNT(r.Id) AS TotalReviews 
FROM 
    dbo.Services AS s
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.Reviews AS r ON s.Id = r.ServiceId
ORDER BY 
    s.Id DESC
    OFFSET @page ROWS FETCH NEXT @pageSize ROWS ONLY;
```

The error is I need to include either average or group by clause but how would that look like I can't figure out?
Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Hav you had a look at the documentation on aggregation, and what the `GROUP BY` looks like? What didn't you understand about it?

Comment: Here is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for the `group by` clause. It is very comprehensive.

Comment: What doesn't work about `GROUP BY s.Id`

Comment: @S.Minchev Can you add sample data and table script with expected output . So, anyone can try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You are using this code
- I am using `SQL PARTITION BY` to divide the result set into partitions and perform computation on each subset of partitioned data.

```
    DECLARE @page int = 0;
    DECLARE @pageSize int = 10;
    
    SELECT 
        s.Id, COUNT (r.Id) OVER (PARTITION BY r.Id) AS TotalReviews 
    FROM 
        dbo.Services AS s
    LEFT JOIN 
        dbo.Reviews AS r ON s.Id = r.ServiceId
    ORDER BY 
        s.Id DESC
        OFFSET @page ROWS FETCH NEXT @pageSize ROWS ONLY;
```